# davidjbradshaw iframe-resizer: how to call IFrame page methods from Angular 9

Tags: angular, iframe-resizer

I am running an Angular 9 SPA inside an iframe and using davidjbradshaw iframe-resizer to dynamically resize the iframe to fit the Angular page so that the user never sees a scroll bar inside the iframe.

On Angular pages that exceed the height of the viewport, ngb modal popups are often displayed outside the viewport.  The user then has to scroll the parent page to find the popup.  For simplicity, I would like to display the popup near the top of the IFramed page and scroll the parent page to top so that it is always visible.

If one tries to scroll the parent page from an IFramed page directly, you get a cross domain scripting violation. davidjbradshaw iframe-resizer offers the ability to circumvent such violations using methods similar to the ones it uses to resize the iframe.  In his [IFrame Page Methods documentation](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/docs/iframed_page/methods.md), Damon offers a method to scroll the parent page to top like so:

```
if ('parentIFrame' in window) {
    parentIFrame.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

The ('parentIFrame' in window) condition is positive at runtime. So the global variable parentIFrame must exist.  But the parentIFrame reference is undefined in TypeScript and I don't know how to get a handle to it from inside Angular 9 so that it will transpile.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ('parentIFrame' in window) {
    const parentIFrame = window["parentIFrame"];
    parentIFrame.scrollTo(0, 0);
 }
```